# getting current hour, minutes and seconds in iPhone

Tags: iphone, datetime, time, timezone, timestamp

How can I get the current hour, minutes, and seconds from this?

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
```

Thanks! I want to have 3 int variables with the values stored in them, not a string which displays the values.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use [`NSDateComponents`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateComponents), which is a bit tricky (not to mention verbose!) since you need to understand a bit about the way Cocoa handles calendars. There's a great intro in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtDates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000183-BCIDBADB); here's a modified excerpt:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents *components =
                    [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];

NSInteger hour = [components hour];
NSInteger minute = [components minute];
NSInteger second = [components second];
```

Comment: [gregorian autorelease] at the end surely, to prevent memory leaks

Comment: autorelease, NSHourCalendarUnit, NSMinuteCalendarUnit, and NSSecondCalendarUnit are all deprecated.